# Select non repeating non repeating columns base on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this table and I am trying to get the latest `analysis_id`

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | repo_id | analysis_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 1  |   20    |      3      |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 2  |   20    |      4      |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 3  |   20    |      5      |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 4  |   21    |      6      |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 5  |   22    |      7      |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

So how do I get the largest number from `analysis_id` without the repeating `repo_id`

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | repo_id | analysis_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 3  |   20    |      5      |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 4  |   21    |      6      |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 5  |   22    |      7      |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

A general MySQL 8+ friendly solution uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY repo_id ORDER BY analysis_id DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, repo_id, analysis_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `group by`

```
SELECT MAX(id) ,repo_id ,MAX(analysis_id)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY repo_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5+ you may use

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM tablename t2
                   WHERE t1.repo_id = t2.repo_id
                     AND t1.id < t2.id )
```